# moving items up and and down in a sub-sub array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to set up functions to allow the user to move items in a scope up or down by an index. I have no problem doing this if th it is 1 level down in the json i am attaching to the scope, but when it is three levels down my code seems to be acting very odd.

Here's what the logic in the controller looks like for the first level down (this works fine)

```
    var move = function (origin, destination, parent) {
            var temp = $scope.dataBlocks.selections[parent].types[destination];
            $scope.dataBlocks.selections[parent].types[destination] = $scope.dataBlocks.selections[parent].types[origin];
            $scope.dataBlocks.selections[parent].types[origin] = temp;
        };
    $scope.blockMoveUp = function(index, parent) {
        move(index, index - 1, parent);
    };

    $scope.blockMoveDown = function(index, parent) {
        move(index, index + 1, parent);
    };
```

Where the click function just passes the items own index an parent index with a ng-click="blockMoveUp($index, $parent.$index)" on each button. Again this works great, but I tried to apply this logic to 1 level deeper. it has some blocks inside of it, like a child array within child area type scenario that I also want the user to be able to move around.

Here is my attempt:

```
var moveInner = function (origin, destination, parent, granp) {
        var temp = $scope.dataBlocks.selections[granp].types[parent].blocks[destination];
        $scope.dataBlocks.selections[granp].types[parent].blocks[destination] = $scope.dataBlocks.selections[granp].types[parent].blocks[origin];
        $scope.dataBlocks.selections[granp].types[parent].blocks[origin] = temp;
    };

    $scope.blockMoveUpSmall = function(index, parent, granp) {

        moveInner(index, index - 1, parent, granp);
    };

    $scope.blockMoveDownSmall = function(index, parent, granp) {
        moveInner(index, index + 1, parent, granp);
    };
```

each ng repeat stores a var of it's index with ng init so the the outer most ng repeat looks like

```
<div class="subformWrappers" ng-repeat="selection in dataBlocks.selections" ng-init="selectionIndex = $index">
```

and the next level down

```
    <div class="saPromptType" ng-repeat="type in selection.types" ng-init="typeIndex = $index">
```

and the third level

```
<div class="saPromptTypeSub blocksHere"  ng-repeat="block in type.blocks"ng-init="blockIndex = $index">
```

so the move function looks like

```
ng-click="blockMoveUpSmall($index, typeIndex, selectionIndex)"
```

It moves the items but in a VERY weird fashion. I could not find any pattern to the moving, but it seems the very first click (up or down) seems to work fine, then after that it gets all out of whack. I'm thinking maybe it has to do with the variable im storing in inits perhaps? If I couldn't store init variables could I do a $parent.$parent.$index perhaps to solve this problem?

I am stumped by this problem, I thought it would be pretty straight forward once I could reference the parent most item. Any/all help would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!!

Comment: I think your dealing with multiple scopes. When a child scope does not have an own porperty yet which is read , prototype inheritance kicks in, and you get the value of the parent scope. When writing it will address the scope it belongs to (ng-repeater scope). Hence you end up in a weird mix of having data distributed over scopes/childscope.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix based on this? Thanks!

Comment: A quick test to see if it is the problem you are dealing with is (not angular MVC correct though); grab the controller element, take the scope from it and use that to do you move logic. If that works correct, you are dealing with the multiple scope issue. (This is however wrong in angular MVC architecture. A controller should not address the view, which is what we are doing in this test solution.

Comment: create a demo in plunker. You really want to use `splice()` to switch array elements around

Comment: thanks i'll try and make a plunker when i get home!